# PHP MySQL search script - match only some letters

Tags: php, mysql, search

have search function in my website. Problem is:
if I write word Litmanova it doesn't find anything because in mysql are words litmanovej, litman etc.

Is there any way to find for example result litmanovej if I will put litmanova in search input?
Thank you.

```
function search() {
  echo "<div class='col-md-12' style='margin-top:20px;'>";
  echo "<div id='custom-search-input'>";
  echo "<form action='vyhladavanie' method='GET'>";
  echo "<div class='input-group col-md-12'>";
  echo "<input type='text' class='form-control input-lg' name='query' placeholder='Napíšte slovo, ktoré hľadáte...' />";
  echo "<span class='input-group-btn'>";
  echo "<button class='btn btn-info btn-lg' type='submit' style='background:#cf585b;border:1px #cf585b solid;'>";
  echo "<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-search'></i>";
  echo "</button>";
  echo "</span>";
  echo "</div>";
  echo "</form>";
  echo "</div>";
  echo "</div>";
}


function showVideoResults() {
  global $conn;
  $query = $_GET['query'];
  $query = "SELECT * FROM videos WHERE video_title LIKE '%".$query."%' OR video_description LIKE '%".$query."%' ORDER by video_date DESC";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

  if (!$result) {
    die("Problém" . mysqli_error($conn));
  }

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      $video_id = $row['video_id'];
      $video_title = $row['video_title'];
      $video_date = $row['video_date'];
      $video_description = $row['video_description'];
      $video_link = $row['video_link'];
      $video_category = $row['video_category'];
      $video_url = $row['video_url'];

      echo "<div class='col-md-4'>";
      echo "<a href='video/$video_id-$video_url'>";
      echo "<h3 class='meta_title'>$video_title</h3></a>";

      echo "</div>";
  }
}
```

Comment: Closest thing I can think of would be the LIKE statement which allows simple pattern matching: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is no "simple" way of doing this, but you can play around with [MATCH AGAINST](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html).

There are some nice examples [here](https://www.mullie.eu/mysql-as-a-search-engine/).

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do any changes to your code. You need to change your database table column's definition

You need to add COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI to your column's definition.

```
ALTER TABLE videos 
 MODIFY COLUMN video_title VARCHAR(…) CHARACTER SET UTF8 COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI;
```